# GLKit glkView:drawInRect: not called when Control Center is open

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I noticed that whenever the Control Center is being used on the iPhone, `glkView:drawInRect:` of my underlying app is not being called - hence the animation appears frozen. This happens as soon as the interaction with the Control Center starts - even when majority of the app is still visible. Animations that are not OpenGL based continue running just fine.

Is there any way to make the app call this method despite the Control Center showing, or is this an inherent limitation of OpenGL?

Comment: This is not an OpenGL limitation but most likely is a GLKit fail. I would avoid anything but the vector and matrix part of this kit. In general a display link (CADisplayLink) is what controls the triggering of the draw. This class has some options about when to trigger or not, for instance if I remember correctly the default will even pause the loop if the screen is being scrolled by the user. So this is most likely what the issue is. The second guess is that a notification is triggered that the app resigned active which pauses the GLKView.

Comment: The app resigned active is not posted, I'll check into other options though. Thanks!